# Custom actions not appearing in the Trigger/Action settings page

Tags: rules

I am developing a custom module which defines custom Triggers and Custom actions.
When I add or change an action, this action doesn't inmediatelly appear in the select list of the Triggers admin page.

I refresh, flush all caches and even activate/desactivate the [Trigger Unlock](http://drupal.org/project/triggerunlock) module (which seems to work), but now when I create a new custom action, I go nuts to make it appear.

You can appreciate in the image and code what I am talking about (notice the Description has not changed after update).

[image]

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */
function commercegate_action_info() {
    return array(
        'commercegate_show_message' => array(
            'description' => t('Show message 1.'),
            'type' => 'commercegate',
            'configurable' => false,
            'hooks' => array(
                'commercegate' => array('callback_sale','callback_cargeback'),
            )
        ),
        'commercegate_show_message2' => array(
            'description' => t('Show message 2.'),
            'type' => 'commercegate',
            'configurable' => false,
            'hooks' => array(
                'commercegate' => array('callback_sale','callback_cargeback'),
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

Anyone familiar with this problem? Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

To allow a new action to appear on the triggers page, you need to visit the administration page at admin/settings/actions, or call [actions_synchronize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--actions.inc/function/actions_synchronize/6).

Comment: I have tried that, and it makes sense.. but no luck. In the actions admin page my custom actions are described but as much as I change them in the `hook_action_info()` the changes are not reflected...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually `hook_rules_action_info()` not `hook_action_info()`.

Comment: Actually, I just realized you might not be creating a rules action...but there it is if someone else has an issue creating a rules action.

Answer (score 0):

try this: uninstall and reinstall your module.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions, sometimes it automatically is deselected.